# how do I export memberof to a CSV correctly with only the CN names

Tags: powershell

```
Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter * |Where-Object {$_.name -like "Users"}|ForEach-Object { Get-ADUser -SearchBase $_.DistinguishedName -Filter * -Properties *}|select name, memberof|export-csv .\output.csv
```

I get Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection as the output for memberof

Comment: Don't forget to ask your question.

Comment: Yep. I'm pretty sure that I know what you want but this is a horribly written question.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It's just a statement. There _is_ no question.

Comment: I used question in the sense of that is the way that SO categorizes the post.

Comment: What exactly do you get when you try the code I provided? How exactly is that wrong? What exactly do you want the output to be?

Comment: first I wanted  the csv file to contain  the  security group names without format problems then I wanted them to be separated.

Answer (score 0):

```
Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter * |Where-Object {$_.name -like "Users"}|ForEach-Object { Get-ADUser -SearchBase $_.DistinguishedName -Filter * -Properties *}|select name, @{n='memberof'; e={$_.Memberof -join '~'}} | export-csv .\output.csv
```

I decided to delimit the MemberOf using the tilde since there was no detail in the question regarding the result that you were actually after.

Comment: sorry I am looking for the CN security group name..so  user name security groups they belong to

Comment: You should update your post to be a question that actually represents what you want.

Comment: `-Filter *` ಠ_ಠ

Comment: @WrightRobert this is one reason why you need to specify your question up front. Someone answered using what they thought might be applicable only to hear "nope, that's not it." Be specific. Nobody likes to go back and forth with guesses.

Comment: sorry about that

Comment: @WrightRobert No need to apologize; instead, update your "question" so that it actually asks a specific question.

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter *|Where-Object {$_.name -like "Users" -and "No GPO" }|
ForEach-Object { Get-ADUser -SearchBase $_.DistinguishedName -Filter * -Properties *}|
select Name, Office, @{n=’MemberOf’; e= {( $_.memberof | % { (Get-ADObject $_).Name }) -join “,” }}|
export-csv C:\Member_list_Output.csv  -NoTypeInformation
```